My plum tree use to produce Plus how do I get rid of the fungus on the tree
Plum Tree - it hasn't produced in awhile. On one side the lower branches have not had any plums, should I cut the whole branch off? Plus it has fungus. What should I do?
The fungus is light green almost white.
Can you scrub the bark with soap?

Pics would help.  Are you sure its a fungus and not a lichen?

Photos are a necessity here, as we'll need to see the sun exposure that the entire tree receives. So - close-ups of the "fungus" and a couple of distance shots of the entire tree.

In addition to the picture, how old is the tree, and is it a standard, semi-dwarf, or dwarf? How is the soil's fertility? What breed is it?

You can try to save your Plum Tree by pruning and removing all infected and dead twigs and branches. Avoid overhead irrigation, as splashing water is a common way of spreading the infection. You can try to save your Plum Tree by pruning out the affected areas 24 past the area of infection; the best time to prune Your Plum Tree would be spring for young trees or midsummer for older trees. You want to spray your plum tree for fungus during the dormant season, which is late winter to early spring before the flowers open and the leaves have opened.

Without photos, we cannot be sure that the "fungus" isn't lichen, which is what, to me, it seems to be. Making a rash diagnosis can cause harm.

You can use a winter spray of copper oxychloride or lime sulfur which will remove the lichen and any disease or insects that have overwintered. You could even give it a gentle soapy scrub.

You need to research Integrated Pest Management. You NEVER treat until you identify the pest. And Lichen does no harm to trees, so why would you try to eliminate it?
